# Get value from json in LogicApp Two/Three Levels Down

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

Absolute newb question here how do I get a value two levels down in the JSON data with Azure Logic Apps? The web-hook is sending in: [Image of incoming JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q75j.png)

I need the value for shipping/address/city...

I have been trying to run @triggerBody()?['shipping']['address']['city'] but it can't find address (obviously I am doing something wrong).

I just need some syntax to continue and your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workaround is to use `Parse_JSON` connector to get the inner values of JSON. Just use the sample Schema in `Use sample payload to generate schema` and it fetches the inner values.
Below is the screenshot of my logic app.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That is super cool - thanks! I know I should have known this - but I couldn't get the right Google keywords to show me. Thank you again. It works great.